# bindItems() adds the same date for each CustomListItem

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

we're currently working on two lists. One is filled with attachments, the other with a timeline.

Both are lists (View file):

```
<IconTabFilter
    icon="sap-icon://attachment"
    key="AttachmentTab"
    text="{i18n>Attachments}">
    <List
        id="AttachmentList"
        includeItemInSelection="true">
    </List>
</IconTabFilter>

<IconTabFilter
    icon="sap-icon://work-history"
    key="TimelineTab"
    text="{i18n>History}">
    <List
        id="Timeline"
        includeItemInSelection="true">
    </List>
</IconTabFilter>
```

Both use similar oData services to bind the data to the view. The only difference is the CustomListItem. Each CustomListItem shows the same information. When calling the webservice directly we get different entries.

We tried it with a StandardListItem too, but neither worked (Controller file):

```
if (evt.getParameter("key") === "AttachmentTab") {
    var template = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        type: "Active",
        title: "{Objecttext}",
        description: "{Filename}",
        icon: {
            path: "Type",
            formatter: fis.eim.approval.util.Formatter.attachmentIcon
        },
        press: this.handleAttachmentPress
    });

    this.byId("AttachmentList").bindItems(
        "/Invoices(id='" + id + "')/Attachments",
        template
    );
}

if (evt.getParameter("key") === "TimelineTab") {
    var template = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
        content: [
            new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({
                title: "{Heading}"
            }),
            new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{Text}"
            })
        ]
    });

    this.byId("Timeline").bindItems({
        path: "/Invoices(id='" + id + "')/Timeline",
        template: template
    });

}
```

It does not work for the history timeline though, the attachments are presented just fine.

We have no idea how to debug that issue any futher. Any recommendations on what could go wrong with the bindItems function?

Edit: oData model log after bindItems() function call

```
oData:
Approvals('0000000000014886'):
Approvals('0000000000015641'):
Approvals('0000000000016369'):
Approvals('0000000000016370'):
Approvals('0000000000016492'):
Attachments(id='foobar'):
Attachments(id='barfoo'):
Timeline(Belnr='',Gjahr='',Bukrs='',EdcObject=''):
LineItems(Id='0000000000000000',Rblgp='000005'): 
LineItems(Id='0000000000016369',Rblgp='000002'): 
LineItems(Id='0000000000016370',Rblgp='000003'): 
LineItems(Id='0000000000016370',Rblgp='000004'):
```

The interesting part is that all other oData calls have parameters, but not the timeline. When opening the subtree of the element, we can see the Heading and Text that is repeated multiple times for all other Timeline entries.

So the question is, where are the other Timeline entries? The network tab reveals, that all entries were loaded, and only the last one of that json response is in the oData model.

Kind regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably the (counter-intuitive) [Javascript scope for variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx); it only has global scope or function scope, not block scope.

So most likely variable `template` -- although defined in each `if` statement -- is basically just the same object for each list.

You may try giving the second template a different variable name.

EDIT: Hmmm, you may be right... I have tested it with your code (same variable name) and it seems to work just fine with JSONModel using dummy data, see working example below:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
  onInit: function(oEvent) {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({
      Attachments: [{
        "Objecttext": "Coretta",
        "Filename": "Wagner"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Leo",
        "Filename": "Smith"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Latasha",
        "Filename": "Chavez"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Lavern",
        "Filename": "Langfeldt"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Dale",
        "Filename": "Santana"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Judy",
        "Filename": "Ponthieux"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Alonzo",
        "Filename": "Vanderlinden"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Lupita",
        "Filename": "Mulvehill"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Polina",
        "Filename": "Cowen"
      }, {
        "Objecttext": "Theresia",
        "Filename": "Alvarez"
      }],
      Timeline: [{
        "Heading": "Geoff",
        "Text": "Popsikle"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Esperanza",
        "Text": "Tupper"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Janelle",
        "Text": "Proctor"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Maria",
        "Text": "Kirchner"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Roberto",
        "Text": "Dellinger"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Barkat",
        "Text": "Parham"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Brandon",
        "Text": "Holcombe"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Amela",
        "Text": "Potate"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Eugene",
        "Text": "Tang"
      }, {
        "Heading": "Kehinde",
        "Text": "Clanton"
      }]
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);

  },

  handleIconTabBarSelect: function(evt) {
    if (evt.getParameter("key") === "AttachmentTab") {
      var template = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        type: "Active",
        title: "{Objecttext}",
        description: "{Filename}",
        icon: "sap-icon://download"
      });

      this.byId("AttachmentList").bindItems(
        "/Attachments",
        template
      );
    }

    if (evt.getParameter("key") === "TimelineTab") {
      var template = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
        content: [
          new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({
            title: "{Heading}"
          }),
          new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{Text}"
          })
        ]
      });

      this.byId("Timeline").bindItems({
        path: "/Timeline",
        template: template
      });

    }
  }

});

var app = new sap.m.App({});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
});

app.addPage(oView);
app.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

  <title>SAPUI5 template</title>

  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

  <script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View controllerName="view1.initial" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
      <IconTabBar id="idIconTabBar" select="handleIconTabBarSelect">
        <items>
          <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://attachment" key="AttachmentTab" text="Attachments">
            <List id="AttachmentList" includeItemInSelection="true">
            </List>
          </IconTabFilter>

          <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://work-history" key="TimelineTab" text="History">
            <List id="Timeline" includeItemInSelection="true">
            </List>
          </IconTabFilter>
        </items>
      </IconTabBar>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>

</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe your ODataModel is not updated correctly? Can you check with the network tab in your browser if the correct data is been loaded upon switching tabs?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference (and we tested it with a different name, hasn't helped), because the object is always changed before going into the bindItems. But we also tried adding the template code into the bindItems function which didn't work either.

Comment: I updated the question above and added a log of the oData model (which means console.log(this.getView().getModel()) after the bindItems() function call.

Comment: As you can see from my working example above, the error is certainly not in your code rendering the tabs and lists. Can you also provide the code how you retrieve your OData resultsets?

Comment: Which code are you refering to? The ABAP side? The front end call in UI5 can be seen above, it's not more than the bindItems function. It's doing all the magic, or in this case not.

Comment: You're right... I'm afraid my knowledge ends here :( As I'm a Java guy, I have non to zero knowledge of the ABAP side of things, but to me it seems the retrieval of data is not correct. If you call the service URL / entityset directly in a browser, I suspect you get the same results? I.e. `http://yourdomain/yourservice/Invoices(id='123')/Timeline`

Comment: Yes, the call works correctly. I guess it's a bug somewhere in the UI5 library, what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74177/discussion-between-qualiture-and-deftoned).

Comment: I found another solution, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because we weren't able to fix the bindItems function, we created a workaround with the read function of the oDataModel.

```
this.getView().getModel().read(
    "/Invoices(id='" + id + "')/Timeline",
    {
        success : (function(data) {
            this.byId("Timeline").destroyItems();

            data.results.forEach((function(text) {
                var template = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
                    content: [
                        new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({
                            title: text.Heading.trim()
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Text({
                            text: text.Text.trim()
                        })
                    ]
                });
                template.addStyleClass("historyListItem");

                this.byId("Timeline").addItem(template);
            }).bind(this));
        }).bind(this),
        error : (function(error) {
            this._showErrorMessage(error);
        }).bind(this)
    }
);
```

We take the results and for each data entry we create a CustomListItem and add it to the list with addItem. Before that we call destroyItems, because otherwise it would add the same entries again after each function call.

It's not the solution we've wished for but an alternative to make it work until we've find a better solution.